# matrix product with numpy.dot()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to calculate the product:

tA*M*B

where A, B are two vectors and M is a squared matrix, tA is the transposed A. The result should be a number.

Numpy has the `dot()` function that multiplies arrays and matrix: is there a way I can use it to calculate my product in a single blow?

I am using python 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
import numpy

#Generate Random Data
M = numpy.random.normal(0,1,9).reshape(3,3)
A = numpy.random.normal(0,1,3)
B = numpy.random.normal(0,1,3)

#The Operation
numpy.dot(A, numpy.dot(M,B) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools) function

```
reduce(numpy.dot,[tA,M,B])
```

This is equivalent to

```
numpy.dot(numpy.dot(tA,M),B)
```

From the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools)

> `reduce(function, sequence)` returns a single value constructed by calling the binary function function on the first two items of the sequence, then on the result and the next item, and so on.

An easy to understand example from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce) is

> `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`

Whether it's worth using `reduce` in your case is debatable. However it clarifies the code if you have a long string of matrix multiplications. Compare the following, equivalent lines of code that multiply tA, M1, M2, M3, and B together.

```
print numpy.dot(numpy.dot(numpy.dot(numpy.dot(tA,M1),M2),M3),B)
print reduce(numpy.dot,[tA,M1, M2, M3,B])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.einsum` gives more control over `dot` operations.  There's some debate, though, about when it is faster or slow than `np.dot`, and whether it consumes too much memory (when the matricies are very big

```
A=np.arange(1,4)
B=10*np.arange(3,6)
M=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
np.dot(A,np.dot(M,B))
np.einsum('i,ij,j',A,M,B)
```